# How get HDD Serial ID in 64 bit window 8.1 with c# .net

Tags: c#

I'm using:

```
private String HDDId()
{            
  String serialNo = string.Empty;
  DriveListEx diskInfo = new DriveListEx();
  diskInfo.Load();            
  return serialNo = diskInfo[0].SerialNumber;
}
```

But it doesn't work in 64 bit Windows 8.1 and it says incorrect format. I don't know how fix this

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using an external DLL (probably from here, although you don't specify it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16941/Get-Physical-HDD-Serial-Number-without-WMI ) which uses native code.

The released DLL on that page is only for 32-bit. If you want to use it on 64 bit (as the remarks in the article say) you need to compile it for 64 bit with the right include/lib folders.

Quoting the page:

> This build is for Windows XP 32 bit systems. If you need it for Vista or 64 bit systems, you should select the right include and lib folders when building and should not use the additional DLLs from the release.zip archive, since they are 32 bit for Windows XP.

Comment: ...or set Target = x86 for the C# project.

Comment: Right, but that's a workaround to the problem, not the solution :-)

Comment: Hi Jcl,Thanks for your answer.but pls what should i do to fix them.

Comment: Well, compile the library you are using in 64 bits. I don't know the library or know how it is compiled, just presumed you were using it.